# Javascript Async buffer copy

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, blob, arraybuffer, typed-arrays

So I know this might be a long-shot, but perhaps someone could help.

Is there any way I could copy a buffer asynchronously? Possibly by using a blob somehow? Below is an example of something kinda along the lines of what I'm looking for (obviously doesn't work, just to illustrate). Need this to work client side.

```
var fromBuffer = new Uint8Array(1056); //just some random data
var bufferToCopyTo;
var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
req.open("GET", "fromBuffer", true);
req.responseType = "blob";

req.onload = function(e) {
  bufferToCopyTo = req.response;

};

req.send();
//continue while buffer makes a copy in the background?
```

Comment: What exactly do you need this for?

Comment: For client side multithreading. Trying to copy the buffers to pass to the workers in the background while the serial part of the code is running. Its for a video decoder

Comment: I'd look into [`postMessage`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/postMessage) and friends that use the structured cloning algorithm.

Comment: No, for that you wouldn't copy the buffer at all but *transfer* it to the background worker.

Comment: I do need to copy because of no shared memory. All the workers need their own copy to work on

Comment: Then each worker should make its copy and transfer the buffer to the next one who needs the original. Assuming the buffer is large enough that the time to copy it does matter.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there any way I could copy a buffer asynchronously?

No, a buffer cannot be copied while other code is running as otherwise there might a race condition to access/write elements of the buffer.

What you can however do, if the copying is taking an abnormal amount of time and chunking doesn't help, is to [transfer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Transferable) the buffer to a background worker, make a copy of it in there, and transfer both back to the main thread. This of course means that the buffer cannot be used while it is being copied.

Comment: I'm afraid you're right :(. It was worth a shot though.